# server sent event: How to hold connection by php script

Tags: php, server-sent-events

Currently I'm trying to use server sent events following this manual:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events
There they are using an endless loop in the PHP script. However regularly the execution time of the script is limited by the server. How can one hold the connection without executing the PHP script for an endless time?

Comment: You would either need to set the [max_execution_time](http://php.net/max_execution_time) longer or on client side re-request the page. This is called long polling.

Comment: Thanks for this info! In the meantime it seems to me that server-sent events are not the proper tool for my project: When starting I assumed that one can send a broadcast to all clients but if I learned it correctly this is not possible directly as each client starts the script separately when notifying and the script can only send to that client. I intend to user simple polling now.

Comment: It is possible to broadcast using long polling by just having your script check a file/database for newer information periodically in your infinite loop.